# How to generate coin address using bitcoin-ruby?

Tags: ruby, bitcoin

Generate bitcoin address using [bitcoin-ruby](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby) is easy how do i generate all the other coin addresses (e.g Litecoin, Dogecoin)

Comment: How many addresses does it generate?

Comment: It generate "n" number of addresses until i stop the process

Comment: Are you looking to generate a bitcoin address or a altcoin?

Comment: Not only bitcoin address, litecoin, dogecoin etc

Comment: Ok... Are you looking to generate a vanity address or just any old address.

Comment: Just now i got this [link](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby), if possible tell me how do i generate litecoin, dogecoin addresses

Comment: @nahtnam i modified the question

Comment: That is a little out of my league... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the addresses is a single version-byte that ends up defining the first character of the address. Bitcoin-ruby has the definition for several networks, including namecoin, litecoin and dogecoin.

To use a different network, just set it before doing anything else:

`Bitcoin.network = :namecoin`

Now you can generate a namecoin address like usual:

`Bitcoin.generate_address`

or:

`Bitcoin::Key.generate`